# Events for back/forward button?

Tags: javascript

If you go to http://www.deviantart.com/ and wait a few seconds so the javascript loads under the hood you can click a link and instead of going to the link you'll go to `#/someId`. You can hit back/forward. I believe i saw similar behavior on other sites but without using `#` in the url.

How do i do an event like make something visible or collapse something and undo (or redo) the event with the back/forward button?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's making use of [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). [Here](http://html5.gingerhost.com/) is a sample page making use of this technique.

If you want to implement this, I really recommend using [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js). It covers some cross-browser issues that you'll otherwise run in to.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Backbone.js's router functionality](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)  is the best solution I've found for this. [This tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/) explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through jquery libraries...

Check out this for the visible and collapse
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/